# Capistrano "do nohup python" works, "do nohup ruby" does not

Tags: python, ruby, capistrano, background-process

I am getting very frustrated trying to write a fairly simple Cap script that will stop and start some daemon processes I have running on remote boxes.

essentially,

```
run "for I in {1..40}; do nohup python ~/pydaemon.py >/dev/null 2>/dev/null & done"
```

works perfectly.  I enter my password and it executes, then I check the box and I have 40 daemons running.

```
run "for I in {1..40}; do nohup ruby ~/rbdaemon.rb >/dev/null 2>/dev/null & done"
```

never creates daemonized instances of the ruby script.  On the Cap side, it tells me

```
"executing "for I in {1..40}; do nohup ruby ~/rbdaemon.rb >/dev/null 2>/dev/null & done""
```

, no errors, but when I check the box nothing is running.

I've run the ruby command from an SSH login and it works fine.  Am I missing something, anything I should try, etc?  Thanks guys.  Really banging my head against this-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redirecting the ruby daemon's stdout and stderr to files, instead of /dev/null. It's probably telling you what's wrong!

Comment: Thanks Jeremy that helped me to find the answer :)  Turned out that RVM was not set up properly when I was running Cap tasks, so the remote boxes didn't know where to find my gems.